# Return substring from Excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to find a formula to extract account numbers from cells that can contain additional information. An account number will always start with an "A" or a "U" and then have 6 numbers, e.g. A123456 or U654321.

A cell can have just the account number, or it can have additional data, e.g. "ADT CASH DEPOSIT      A235999" or "FNB APP PAYMENT FROM               A230275"

Comment: Is the account number always at the end and does every cell always contain the account number or are there occasions when the cell won't have it in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an alternative function which searches the other way around (first letter, than number), avoids searching at places where the number could not fit and does it case-insensitively:

```vb
Public Function AccountNo(thiscell As Range) As String
    Dim numlen As Integer, cellText As String
    Dim i As Long, rest As String, firstletter As String

    AccountNo = ""
    numlen = 6
    cellText = thiscell.Text
    For i = 1 To Len(cellText) - numlen
        firstletter = UCase(Mid(cellText, i, 1))
        If (firstletter = "A" Or firstletter = "U") Then
            rest = Mid(cellText, i + 1, numlen)
            If IsNumeric(rest) Then
                AccountNo = firstletter & rest
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks - this works great (as does the other suggestion, but this one caters for the lower case letters too). Now my problem is that for some reason the UDF only wants to work in this workbook, but when I add it to my Personal.XLSB it doesn't work [even if I reference it as Personal.XLSB!AccountNo()] - not does it want to work as an add-in. But that's just me being stupid I'm sure - will figure it out.

Comment: Referencing `PERSONL.XLS!AccountNo(A1)` does work here. The alternative is to put the code in a new workbook and save it as an AddIn.

Answer (score 1):

This UDF detects the account number, no matter where it is:

```vb
Public Function accounts(cellText As String)
    accounts = ""
    numberlength = 6
    posText = 0
    lenText = Len(cellText)
    For i = 1 To lenText
        midText = Mid(cellText, i, numberlength)
        If IsNumeric(midText) = True Then
            posText = i
            letterText = Mid(cellText, posText - 1, 1)
            If (letterText = "A" Or letterText = "U") Then
                accounts = Mid(cellText, posText - 1, numberlength + 1)
                i = lenText
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Copy the code, open Visual Basic / Macros, under *ThisWorkbook* insert a new module and paste the code on the right side.

To use it, if the text is in cell `A1`, then in cell `B1` you have to put `=accounts(A1)`.